# Measured data not normalized - but should it be?

Tags: normal-distribution, repeated-measures, normalization, measurement

I'm analyzing some data at the moment and I just stumbled over the situation that a part of itseems to be not normalized.
*Background:* Several gas sensors were measured and the value of a resistor is connected to the same applied gas concentration. All 14 resistors can be seen in the following:

[image: Plot]

As visible, the resistors 4 to 14 have a more or less equal median but the resistors 1 to 3 do not. I wonder what this means. As it can be seen on [boxplots](https://towardsdatascience.com/understanding-boxplots-5e2df7bcbd51) the median is centered when the data is normalized. 
So what does, in return, mean? Are the sensors not working properly? Or is it some other effect?

As I didn't conduct the measuremnts, it is a bit difficult to guess the reason. Maybe those resistors were located where the gas streamed in. 
But in advance, just only considering the data: What does it mean when the median of the boxplots of the resistors 1 to 3 are not on the same height as all the others?

When I would ignore those other sensors (4-14) I wouldn't assume there is something going on.

[Data](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Gas+sensor+array+temperature+modulation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by `the median is centered when the data is normalized`? Centered how and normalized in what way?

Anyway, the boxplots in your image are showing you that resistors 1 to 3 are different in distribution from the others (boxplots are really for plotting distributions not just for medians), in that they are skewed and have more outliers.

Then again, I would also say that resistors 4 to 7 are more similar to each other, while resistors 8 to 14 are another cluster since they have smaller variances.

But to the point of the question, I can't tell you what is going on with the resistors, I can only tell you that the first three resistors have smaller medians compared to the others for the variable R [MOhm] (and also different overall distributions). So I guess we could say that these resistors are underperforming / not working as the others?

Comment: Isn't that correct, that the median is in the center of the boxplot when the data is normalized? Then, 50% of the data is above the median line and 50 % below?

Yes, true, probably there are three clusters. 
When the median is lower than compared to all the other sensors: Can I connect some behaviour with that? Maybe, to make it easier: What does it mean when the median is very close at one side of the box? The box is carrying 50 % of the data and when the median is at the lower edge I'd assume there would be many outliers below the box. But they are above..

Comment: @Ben No that is not true, the median will be at the center of the boxplot only if your data is very symmetric, such that the median is very close to the mean. Normalization can help in some cases, but in general no. What you can conclude from the boxplots is that the first three resistors are very asymetrically distributed (skewed) "down" and have a lot of outliers "up", also all the resistors are limited by zero, so negative values are probably not possible.

Comment: But on https://statweb.stanford.edu/~naras/jsm/NormalDensity/NormalDensity.html it is given: "All normal distributions are symmetric and have bell-shaped density curves with a single peak".
Thus, as it is not symmetric, it must not be normal?

Comment: @Ben (Theoretical) normal distributions have symmetric distributions where the mean is equal to the median. However, in your case, the distributions are clearly not normal, so you cannot expect that. In general, if the distribution is not symmetric, then it's also likely not normal. There are also more formal tests for normality.

Comment: Yes, but that's what I said?

Comment: @Ben No, you used stronger language. It does not necessarily follow that if a distribution is (slightly) skewed then it's not normal, however it is a good indicator.

Comment: Ah, ok, I have to think about that a skewed distribution might be normal though. Doesn't fit into my mind actually :)